# Google Analytics API - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to follow the Google Analytics API tutorial given [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api). I've followed it step by step. Here are my files

**client_secrets.json**

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback/"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

**hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build

from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

CLIENT_SECRETS = 'client_secrets.json'
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = '%s is missing' % CLIENT_SECRETS

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
  message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

TOKEN_FILE_NAME = 'analytics.dat'

def prepare_credentials():
  storage = Storage(TOKEN_FILE_NAME)
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
  return credentials

def initialize_service():
  http = httplib2.Http()

  #Get stored credentials or run the Auth Flow if none are found
  credentials = prepare_credentials()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  #Construct and return the authorized Analytics Service Object
  return build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
```

**hello_analytics_api_v3.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

# import the Auth Helper class
import hello_analytics_api_v3_auth

from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError


def main(argv):
  # Initialize the Analytics Service Object
  service = hello_analytics_api_v3_auth.initialize_service()

  try:
    # Query APIs, print results
    profile_id = get_first_profile_id(service)

    if profile_id:
      results = get_results(service, profile_id)
      print_results(results)

  except TypeError, error:
    # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

  except HttpError, error:
    # Handle API errors.
    print ('Arg, there was an API error : %s : %s' %
           (error.resp.status, error._get_reason()))

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    # Handle Auth errors.
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run '
           'the application to re-authorize')


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account
    firstAccountId = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the Web Properties for the first account
    webproperties = service.management().webproperties().list(accountId=firstAccountId).execute()

    if webproperties.get('items'):
      # Get the first Web Property ID
      firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all Views (Profiles) for the first Web Property of the first Account
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=firstAccountId,
          webPropertyId=firstWebpropertyId).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first View (Profile) ID
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='2014-01-10',
      end_date='2014-09-08',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'First View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

To test the output, I'm running the command using my terminal as

```
python hello_analytics_api_v3.py
```

Running this opens the browser which asks me to authenticate my Google Account and after that I get a 400 error

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request: `http://localhost:8080/` did not match
>   a registered redirect URI.

How did Google get the `http://localhost:8000/` as redirect URI? This is what I've specified in my Google Developer Console App

> REDIRECT URIS  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback/`
>
> JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: you have typed 8000 are you sure you don't mean 8080?

Comment: @DaImTo No, I'm running my local server on port 8000.

Comment: try this tutorial its probably more up todate.  http://www.marinamele.com/use-google-analytics-api-with-python  in the mean time I think you should double check your client_secret.json wondering if its reading the one from the tutorial instead of the one you created.

Comment: @DaImTo I checked. The `client_secret.json` is being read. The callback URL it goes to has the `client_id` I've sepecified in `client_secret.json`

Comment: it says you are calling http://localhost:8080/ which isn't the same as 8000, if its getting it from that file then its weird.

Comment: @DaImTo I figured out the issue. In my console, I had set up a Web Application. Instead I had to setup a Installed Application, since I'm accessing this over the terminal. Your tutorial pointed me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my console, I had set up a Web Application. Instead I had to setup an Installed Application, since I'm accessing this over the terminal.

A more comprehensive tutorial is given here - http://www.marinamele.com/use-google-analytics-api-with-python